# How to access files / folder from ONLY 2 levels down with regex

Tags: regex

For performance reasons i should access files from 2 folders down.

Currently for one level down I have this regular expression :

`'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'`

To access all subfolders I can use this :

`'test/spec/**/*.js'`

Do you know the best regular expression for accessing only 2 subfolders

Thanks

Comment: These are no regular expressions but brace expansions of your shell.

Comment: Why not just `split` your string on `/\//`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ls -al test/spec/{,*/,*/*/}*.js
```

Also using `find`:

```
find -maxdepth 3 -type f -iname "*.js"
```